# Configure i18next to use warning logs instead of default info level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

Currently I have many logs by `i18next` that make difficult to use the console:

[image]

I need `i18next` to use warning level instead of default info level, in order to be able to filter them.

Im checking [docs](https://i18next.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_init.html) but I dont see any option. My current configuration is:

```js
i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    lng: 'en',
    keySeparator: false,
    addMissing: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },

    resources: {
      en: {
        translations: translationEng
    },
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations'
  })
```

Comment: you want i18next to use warnings, in-order to be able to filter them out? you can disable them but configuring `debug: false`

Comment: I want to filter them using the own console. Not changing my configuration every time I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable `debug: false`, which will disable the default `console.log` stuff.
And and an event listener `missingKey` on the `i18n` instance.

```js
i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: false, // <-- disable default console.log
    lng: 'en',
    keySeparator: false,
    addMissing: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },

    resources: {
      en: {
        translations: translationEng
    },
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations'
  });

i18n.on('missingKey', (lng, namespace, key, fallbackValue) => {
   console.warn(lng, namespace, key, fallbackValue);
})
```

Based on [this code](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/cb780add1fbe5b829bca2d4d56ed201bf8ab82bd/src/Translator.js#L242)

Other option is to use the `options.missingKeyHandler` to pass a custom handler for handing missing keys.

```js
i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: false, // disable this
    lng: 'en',
    keySeparator: false,
    addMissing: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },

    resources: {
      en: {
        translations: translationEng
    },
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    saveMissing: true, // must be enabled
    missingKeyHandler: (lng, ns, key, fallbackValue) => {
       console.warn(lng, ns, key, fallbackValue)
    }
  })
```

Based on [this code](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/cb780add1fbe5b829bca2d4d56ed201bf8ab82bd/src/Translator.js#L223)